# Why is this dictionary not return length 1 for keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, testing, key

For a test that I'm writing, it's supposed to say that only one key has been returned, but instead I am getting that there are 2 keys. I know that the second key is checked.

How do I get to the point where it says there is only one key?

```
def testA2_check_980_ShouldErrWithOnlyOneKeyReturned(self):
       
        #    test 980:  exactly one key returned

        inputDict = {'op': 'check'}
        
        inputDict['cube'] = 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'
        expectedResult = 1
    
        actualResult = check._check(inputDict)
        self.assertEqual(expectedResult, len(actualResult))
```

output : 1 != 2

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: So that we're clear: you're proposing that, starting with a dictionary that has one key-value pair in it, and setting a key-value pair with a *different key*, you expect that, afterwards, there will still only be one key-value pair in the dictionary? **Why**? Also, what is `check._check`, and why should we know anything about it? Also, what is "I know that the second key is check" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
inputDict['cube'] = 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'
```

inserts a key into `inputDict`, giving us a keyset with two keys: `'cube'` and `'op'`.

If you only want one key in the dictionary, either use `del inputDict['op']` or don't insert the `'cube'` key.